# Where's Keyboard Options in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, keyboard

In Freya System Settings under Keyboard there used to be the Options tab with lots of options for configuring 3rd level key, ctrl key position, Alt/Win behavior etc...
Where can I access these options in Loki?

Comment: I'm curious to know what use case do you have for those options, which ones were you looking for? maybe there is a better alternative to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Basically I need this options to make the keyboard behave the same way as a Mac keyboard. Having the control key position right next to space on the left hand side of the keyboard is much more comfortable for me to use shortcuts since I can use my thumb to press control and can maintain all other fingers at their base position. Thus pressing control Q in order to quit an application is just like pressing Q regularly, but with the thumb holding the control key.

Comment: (With the windows style of key placements I would have to use the pinky finger to hold control, but this is exactly the finger I would use to press Q. Alternatively I could move my whole hand out of typing position just to use a shortcut with my thumb on control, so it feels very disruptive to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the AppCenter install Tweak Tools, open Tweak Tools and select Typing to access all these options.